# golang пройтись по массиву в шаблоне

Tags: массивы, golang, шаблоны

Как вывести элементы массива в шаблон

код go:

```
func TakeToRepair(w http.ResponseWriter, rnd render.Render) {
//  rnd.HTML(200, "take_to_repair", nil)
type Table_view struct {
    id         string
    fam        string
    name       string
    lastname   string
    phone      string
    homeadres  string
    numberud   string
    lgotcat    string
    fiovrach   string
    inputdate  string
    inputdate2 string
    numbernar  string
    fioreg     string
    comment    string
}
var db *sql.DB
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:099586741@192.168.0.10/postgres")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, fam, name FROM journal_patient")

bks := make([]*Table_view, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    bk := new(Table_view)
    rows.Scan(&bk.id, &bk.fam, &bk.name)
    bks = append(bks, bk)
}
for _, bk := range bks {
    fmt.Println(bk.id, bk.fam, bk.name)

}
//  var names []string

//  for rows.Next() {
//      var name string
//      names = append(names, name)
//  }

rnd.HTML(200, "take_to_repair", bks)
```

}

код шаблона html

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
     <thead>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Дата записи</td>
        <td>Фамилия</td>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td>Отчество</td>
        <td>Дата рождения</td>
        <td>№ телефона</td>
        <td>Адресс</td>
        <td>Тип льготы</td>
        <td>№ наряда</td>
        <td>Дата наряда</td>
        <td>Имя доктора</td>
        <td>Комментарий</td>
        <td>В очереди</td>
     </thead>
        <tr>
                {{range .}}
                <td>
                        {{.id}}
                </td>
                {{end}}
        </tr>
```

Я отправляю массив bks в html шаблон.
Как можно пройтись по этому массиву в шаблоне и вывести значения?

Comment: Предоставьте минимальный компилируемый пример, демонстрирующий вопрос.

Comment: нужно чтобы в шаблон, между тегами
   
                <td>
                        


                </td>


проставлялся набор данных из массива bks передаваемого respose rnd.HTML(200, "take_to_repair", bks)

Comment: если использую 

     {{ range $key, $value := . }}
     <td>
       {{.Name}}
     </td>
     {{end}}
выводится абсолютно все значения

Comment: Нужен код, который можно запустить на [PlayGolang](https://play.golang.org/) и увидеть поведение, отличающееся от ожидаемого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все разобрался.

В шаблоне в необходимом поле перебрать можно вот так:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
     <thead>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Дата записи</td>
        <td>Фамилия</td>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td>Отчество</td>
        <td>Дата рождения</td>
        <td>№ телефона</td>
        <td>Адрес</td>
        <td>Тип льготы</td>
        <td>№ наряда</td>
        <td>Дата наряда</td>
        <td>Имя доктора</td>
        <td>Комментарий</td>
        <td>В очереди</td>
     </thead>

                {{ range $key, $value := . }}
        <tr>
                <td>{{$value.Id}}</td>                  
                <td></td>
                <td>{{$value.Fam}}</td>
                <td>{{$value.Name}}</td>

        <tr>

        </tr>
                        {{end}}
```

А не получалось изначально потому что я в структуре название переменных с маленькой буквы писал:

```
    type Table_view struct {
    Id         string
    Fam        string
    Name       string
    lastname   string
    phone      string
    homeadres  string
    numberud   string
    lgotcat    string
    fiovrach   string
    inputdate  string
    inputdate2 string
    numbernar  string
    fioreg     string
    comment    string
}
```

Всем спасибо